# App is universal, but AppIcon in asset manager does not have space for iPad icons

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

Xcode shows me the following alerts:

[image: Alert]

- "A 76x76 app icon is required for iPad apps targeting iOS 7.0 and later"
- "A 76x76@2x app icon is required for iPad apps targeting iOS 7.0 and later"

The app is actually Universal.

How can I resolve this alert?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [Attributes Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-general/Chapters/AbouttheUtilityArea.html), make sure that you have checked iPad -> "iOS7 and later" option:

[image: Attributes Inspector]